# Fetch API: PUT request for JSON returning 404 while GET is working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api

I have 1 json file: `{ "clicks": 0 }`

I'm trying to retrieve the data from it and then update it. The GET works, but the PUT does not.

I use Typescript which should not be a problem:

```
  const getClickCounterJsonData = () => fetch(
    'click-counter.json',
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    }
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => myJson);

  // this call is actually added to onClick, but you get the idea
  getClickCounterJsonData().then(data => console.log(data['clicks'])); //this works, returns the actual value of the clicks property
```

Now the not working updating function:

```
      const updateClickCounterJsonData = (newData: any) => fetch(
        'click-counter.json',
        {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(newData)
        }
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(myJson => myJson);

    // again in a onClick function
    updateClickCounterJsonData({ clicks: 5 }).catch(error => console.log(error)); // this returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
   // and also the request in the Network tab says 404 Not Found with a preview text: Cannot PUT click-counter.json
```

Am I not allowed to do PUT requests to a json resource? I'm not super familiar with the topic, but found a lot of resources that this should be possible. The GET works as expected and the PUT seems to be well configurated but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874969/how-can-i-modify-a-json-file-stored-on-server-from-client-side

Answer (score 2):

Servers may route requests based on the HTTP request type - for example express/node.js server provides explicit methods to process PUT, POST and GET requests using `app.put`, `app.post` and `app.get` respectively. The logic of this comes under the umbrella of "request routing". If no route is encountered that matches a request pattern, typically the router is coded to fall through to server code that responds with a `404` error.

Hence you can't just change a `GET` request that works into a `PUT` request and expect the server to adapt - it would need code changes to do so.

Comment: I see. Okay, thanks for the reply! I will stick with MongoDB or Redis. Apparently, I tried to reinvent the hot water for a simpler/quicker solution.